# Xpath: return all nodes that match any one of the conditions

Tags: xpath, saxon

I am trying to fetch two nodes from XML as combined result using OR condition.

Nodes in XML where name = John or name="jim",both should be returned . So basically I expect following result:

```
<person name="John"></person>
<person name="Jim"></person>
```

I have tried XPath function *** //*/person[@name="John"] or  //*/person[@name="Jim"]***

but it gives me only one node.

How to construct Xpath function in this case ?

regards,
Venky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a predicate `person[@name = ('John', 'Jim')]` if we assume Saxon means a Saxon 9 version where XPath 2 or 3 is supported. Of course the right place for your `or` expression would be inside the square brackets `person[@name = 'Jim' or @name = 'John']`.